# height of wrapper div to inside floated items?

Tags: html, css

I have a div '**a**' ( **simple** div)

and div '**b**' which is `float:left`;

I was wondering what is the **correct** method to set the height of div 'a' to be a **perfect wrapper** for div 'b' ( in terms of **height**).

[image]

i know there are some options :

1)set 'a' : overflow:hidden ( it works).

2)set at the end of 'b' div with 'clear':both

- ) i would love to know more options ( besides fixed height to div 'a'...)
- )  and of course , what is the better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Royi Namir; there others mades like [clearfix](http://perishablepress.com/press/2009/12/06/new-clearfix-hack/) like this

**css:**

```
.clearfix:after {
    display: block;
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    }
```

as per the better way `clearfix` & `overflow:hidden` both are better because you no need to write any `extra markup` in your html for every element.